# identifying which variables are leaking memory in python using pympler

Tags: python, memory

I have a python script that has a memory leak, I can see using pympler that my dictionary and list objects are growing by:

```
from pympler import tracker
tr = tracker.SummaryTracker()
tr.print_diff()
```

However I have not figured out how to list the variable names in my code that have the memory leak. Can someone help me list out the variable names and the code usage for that variable name?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it is leaking memory? From your code here we have no idea why it would leak.

Comment: The code I have is rather large and multiple threads. I have no idea where it is leaking memory, if it is my code or a library I am using.  However the process's virtual memory usage keeps growing and growing. Using pympler and printing out the tracker difference I can see that  number of dictionary and list objects keep increasing along with their memory usage.

Comment: However if I print out the objects using the dict() command I can not see any extra variables being created.  Therefore I assume this might be happening inside a library or another object. However I am unsure how to determine which object/library to start looking at, as I can seem to get a list of the objects/variables and their memory usage to see which one is growing.

Comment: Well if that is all you are willing to share at this point, then my only suggestion would be to start systematically commenting out functions or loops that add to the memory and see specifically what lines are doing that.

Comment: Using objgraph I was able to track down the memory usage issue, I was saving the threads to a list, but never removing....

Comment: Well, there you go! :P

Answer (score 2):

From [Pympler's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/#usage-examples):

> Tracking the lifetime of objects of certain classes can be achieved
>   with the Class Tracker. This gives insight into instantiation patterns
>   and helps to understand how specific objects contribute to the memory
>   footprint over time:

```
>>> from pympler import classtracker
>>> tr = classtracker.ClassTracker()
>>> tr.track_class(Document)
>>> tr.create_snapshot()
>>> create_documents()
>>> tr.create_snapshot()
>>> tr.stats.print_summary()
              active      1.42 MB      average   pct
   Document     1000    195.38 KB    200     B   13%
```

Is it what you were looking for?